# Overriding Object's virtual methods

Tags: c#, c++, oop, overriding, swig

I have a class in C++ and I wish to override [ToString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring.aspx), [GetHashCode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode.aspx), and [Equals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47.aspx) in the C# class SWIG generates.

How can I do that? is it possible? (I wouldn't like to derive from the class SWIG generates, of course.. having 2 classes for 1 class will just complicate things and lead to errors and mistakes).

Comment: I think this isn't possible.

Comment: Never used swig.  If swig generates source code, consider making a sed(1) script to edit the source code.

Comment: Can SWIG be configured to generate classes with the `partial` keyword?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I fully understand the question, but if you have access to the source and are prepared to delve into the C# class itself, it's pretty simple to override these classes, take a look at the MSDN references below.

For ToString() see [MSDN how to override ToString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173154%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

For Equals() or == see [MSDN how to override Equals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

For GetHashCode() see [MSDN how to override GetHashCode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182358%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

The only problem I can see with doing this is that if you are generating source code from SWIG (a product I have never used, just to clarify), then there is a possibility that you could override the source code when you output, meaning you would have to write it again.

An option to avoid this would be to use partial classes, so the partial class you generate with SWIG does not overwrite the partial class with the override methods in it.

If you've never used patial classes I'd take a look here: [MSND partial classes guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

These are just some suggestions to tackle your problem!

Comment: Yes, I can configure it to generate partial classes. Thanks.